# Spring Kaka - Seek Offset from beginning

Tags: spring-kafka

I would like to consume messages from the beginning Offset. For this, I have added a property "seekToBeginning"=true in the properties file. My class that has the @KafkaListener implements ConsumerSeekAware and I have overriden the method onPartitionsAssigned() like the below. I would like to know if i'm doing it the right way. This method gets called 3 times (there are 3 partitions). Also, my worry is this method gets called when there is a CommitFailedException also. Pls let me know if the below if correct or should I filter by partition and how. Also pls let me know how to handle this in case of CommitFailedException.

````
    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        if (seekToBeginning)
        {
            assignments.forEach(
                    (topic, action) -> callback.seekToBeginning(topic.topic(), topic.partition()));
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have concurrency = 3 then, yes, it will be called 3 times, once per consumer.

Since 2.3.4, there is a more convenient method:

```java
/**
 * Queue a seekToBeginning operation to the consumer for each
 * {@link TopicPartition}. The seek will occur after any pending offset commits.
 * The consumer must be currently assigned the specified partition(s).
 * @param partitions the {@link TopicPartition}s.
 * @since 2.3.4
 */
default void seekToBeginning(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
```

You need a boolean field to only do the seeks on the initial assignment and not after a rebalance.

If you only have one consumer (concurrency = 1), it can be a simple boolean.

e.g. `boolean initialSeeksDone`.

With concurrency > 1, you need a `ThreadLocal`:

```
ThreadLocal<Boolean> initialSeeksDone;
```

then

```
if (this.initialSeeksDone.get() == null) {
    //seek
    this.initialSeeksDone.set(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gary Russell. I'll implement this solution to not seek offset after a rebalance.